# Assembly SF flag

Tags: assembly, x86, flags

So I have 2 registers, `eax` which holds 0xDEADC0DE and `ebx` which holds 0x1337CA5E.

The first number is bigger than the second one. However, after the `cmp` instruction : `cmp eax, ebx` the `SF` (sign flag) is set. Why ?

Why if the result is positive (`eax` - `ebx`) ?

Comment: The sign flag indicates that the result is *negative,* not *positive.* And indeed, this is the case as 0xdeadc0de - 0x1337ca5e has the sign bit set. What is your question?

Comment: You use the sign flag in signed comparisons in which case `0xdeadc0de` is a negative number hence less than your second operand (note you also have to check the overflow flag). For unsigned comparison check the carry flag which is zero.

Comment: You are probably just a victim of how an assembly debugger displays the value of a register.  It always shows the unsigned value in hex.  But when you are interested in the signed flag then you have to interpret its 2's complement encoded value.  0xdeadc0de has the high bit turned on, the bit that indicates the sign.  And is therefore a negative value, -559038242 in decimal.  0x1337ca5e does not have the high bit set, so it is positive.  So sure, a negative value is always less than a positive value, -559038242 is less than 322423390.

Comment: Thankx @HansPassant

Comment: signed, unsigned, positive, negative, are all irrelevant here.  the result has bit31 set and SF gets bit 31.  The result is 0xC....., bit31 is set so SF is set.  This is in the x86 documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cmp` performs a `sub` (but does not keep the result).

Let's do the same by hand:

```
 reg     hex value   binary value    

 eax = 0xdeadc0de    ‭11011110101011011100000011011110‬
 ebx = 0x1337ca5e    ‭00010011001101111100101001011110‬
  -    ----------
 res   0xCB75F680    11001011011101011111011010000000
```

The flags are set as follows:

```
OF (overflow) : did bit 31 change      -> no
SF (sign)     : is bit 31 set          -> yes
CF (carry)    : is abs(ebx) < abs(eax) -> no  
ZF (zero)     : is result zero         -> no
PF (parity)   : is parity of LSB even  -> no (archaic)
AF (Adjust)   : overflow in bits 0123  -> archaic, for BCD only.
```

As you can see, the result has bit 31 set and thus it is negative.
Just like -3 - 1 = -4 (still negative).
You cannot use the `SF` (sign flag) to determine if `EBX > EAX`. You need to use the `OF` (overflow flag) for signed numbers or the `CF` (carry flag) for unsigned numbers.

**Positive or negative**
The CPU does not know (or care) whether a number is positive or negative. The only person who knows is you. If you test `SF` and `OF`, then you treat the number as signed. If you only test `CF` then you treat the number as unsigned.
In order to help you the processor keeps track of all flags at once. You decide which flags to test and by doing so, you decide how to interpret the numbers.

Comment: The PF will be 0 after the `cmp`. (the bottom 8 bits are `1000 0000` = not even bits set = PF=0)